# AMPscript Function - Math

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I wanted some help for an AMPscript function where i get an error.
I have a data extension with some information like :
Number of points
Amount Transations

I need to display on this email the amount of money they need to go on the next step (like VIP)

So i need to do two functions :

- **5000 - Number of points** = Number of points that i need to go on
  the next step
- **Number of points that i need to go on the next step    / 20** =
  amount of $ that i need to spend to go on the next step.

I have this AMPscript :

```
SET @rowSet = LookupOrderedRows("Loyalty", 0, "Points Asc", "SubscriberKey", _SubscriberKey) 
SET @rowCount = rowcount(@rowSet)

for @i = 1 to @rowCount do 
    var @nombrePointsCumul, @montantTotalTransactions, @pointManquant, @dollarManquant
    SET @row = row(@rowSet, @i)

    SET @nombrePointsCumul = field(@row,"Points") 
    SET @montantTotalTransactions = field(@row,"Transactions") 

    SET @pointManquant = Subtract(5000, @nombrePointsCumul)
    SET @dollarManquant = Divide(@pointManquant, 20)
next @i
```

Comment: What error are you receiving?

Answer (score 0):

For debugging purposes, I'd recommend doing an [**output()**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/output.htm) of values used in your calculations. I'm guessing your issues are data related (e.g. trying to do calculations on values that are not numbers).

```
%%[

   SET @rowSet = LookupOrderedRows("Loyalty", 0, "Points Asc", "SubscriberKey", _SubscriberKey) 
   SET @rowCount = rowcount(@rowSet)

   for @i = 1 to @rowCount do 

       var @nombrePointsCumul, @montantTotalTransactions, @pointManquant, @dollarManquant
       SET @row = row(@rowSet, @i)

       SET @nombrePointsCumul = field(@row,"Points") 
       SET @montantTotalTransactions = field(@row,"Transactions") 

       output(concat("<br>nombrePointsCumul: ",@pointManquant))
       output(concat("<br>montantTotalTransactions: ",@montantTotalTransactions))

       SET @pointManquant = Subtract(5000, @nombrePointsCumul)
       SET @dollarManquant = Divide(@pointManquant, 20)
   next @i

   ]%%
```